# ¿ Hay algun equivalente muy preciso del comando cat de Linux en Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, cmd, shell

Tengo una duda que no encuentro en internet,

Hay alguna forma de usar el comando cat en windows de la misma forma que en linux o una muy similar.

Ejemplo de uso en linux:

```
cat /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Prueba `type NOMBRE_ARCHIVO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías instalar `bash` en alguna de sus diferentes posibilidades (wsl, cygwin, etc).... en todo caso, creo que en `CMD`, se utiliza `type`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/type

No soy un Windows Sysadmin (solo llevo muchos años tratando que las cosas sucedan) así que puede no ser la mejor respuesta.

Comment: Veo que con el git bash me funciona gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el comando Get-Content en **PowerShell** para leer el contenido de un archivo y mostrarlo en la consola.

```html
Get-Content archivo.txt
```